# How to read tomcat logs with logstash

Tags: tomcat, logstash

I am trying to configure logstash. In the wiki I found we can read apache or other systems logs. What is the configuration and steps to read tomcat logs.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat uses Java-Util-Logging.

You can use a direct GELF appender to submit logs from Tomcat to logstash.

You need some changes in your startup-script and the logger config (and two jars):

**/conf/logging.properties**:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, biz.paluch.logging.gelf.jul.GelfLogHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, biz.paluch.logging.gelf.jul.GelfLogHandler


biz.paluch.logging.gelf.jul.GelfLogHandler.host=udp:localhost
biz.paluch.logging.gelf.jul.GelfLogHandler.port=12201
biz.paluch.logging.gelf.jul.GelfLogHandler.level=INFO
```

**/bin/catalina.sh**:

```
if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/logstash-gelf-1.4.2.jar" ] ; then
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_BASE/bin/logstash-gelf-1.4.2.jar:$CATALINA_BASE/bin/json-simple-1.1.jar:$CATALINA_BASE/bin/jedis-2.5.1.jar:$CATALINA_BASE/bin/commons-pool2-2.0.jar
fi
```

**logstash-gelf**:
[logstash-gelf-1.5.2-logging-module.zip](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=biz/paluch/logging/logstash-gelf/1.5.2/logstash-gelf-1.5.2-logging-module.zip)

See also [Changes for logstash-gelf with Tomcat](https://gist.github.com/mp911de/69385b908d129a74b205)

Answer (score 1):

This will likely depend on choice of Java logging framework and how the output from the logging framework is formatted.

The logstash docs give an example log4j input parser: http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.9/inputs/log4j

```
input {
  log4j {
    add_field => ... # hash (optional), default: {}
    charset => ... # string, one of ["ASCII-8BIT", "UTF-8", "US-ASCII", ...] (optional), default: "UTF-8"
    data_timeout => ... # number (optional), default: 5
    debug => ... # boolean (optional), default: false
    format => ... # string, one of ["plain", "json", "json_event"] (optional)
    host => ... # string (optional), default: "0.0.0.0"
    message_format => ... # string (optional)
    mode => ... # string, one of ["server", "client"] (optional), default: "server"
    port => ... # number (required)
    tags => ... # array (optional)
    type => ... # string (required)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.1/inputs/file), you can use ANY log file, it does not matter what source it comes from. You will have to use the input as file and configure other things accordingly!

```
input {
  file {
## Your configuration goes here like file path 
## and other config, check documentation
}
}
```